# Spring Boot Actuator DataSourceHealthIndicator not working for auto-configured DataSource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using an auto-configured DataSource in Spring Boot 1.3.6 and I'm using Actuator's health endpoint.  However, the health endpoint does not include any database component in the output.

My `application.properties` is as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:local
spring.datasource.username=vagrant
spring.datasource.password=vagrant
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

endpoints.enabled=false
endpoints.health.enabled=true
```

The output from the /health endpoint is:

```
{"status":"UP","diskSpace":{"status":"UP","total":499863515136,"free":121851781120,"threshold":10485760}}
```

I enabled trace logging and it looks like Spring Boot is autoconfiguring the health indicators before the datasource.  Here is an excerpt from the trace log (note the timestamps):

```
2016-07-22 10:07:20.976 TRACE 7628 --- [restartedMain] o.s.b.a.condition.OnClassCondition       : Condition OnClassCondition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$DataSourcesHealthIndicatorConfiguration matched due to @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
2016-07-22 10:07:20.977 TRACE 7628 --- [restartedMain] .b.a.a.OnEnabledHealthIndicatorCondition : Condition OnEnabledHealthIndicatorCondition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$DataSourcesHealthIndicatorConfiguration matched due to All default health indicators are enabled by default
2016-07-22 10:07:23.304 TRACE 7628 --- [restartedMain] o.s.b.a.condition.OnClassCondition       : Condition OnClassCondition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$DataSourcesHealthIndicatorConfiguration matched due to @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
2016-07-22 10:07:23.305 TRACE 7628 --- [restartedMain] o.s.b.a.condition.OnBeanCondition        : Condition OnBeanCondition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$DataSourcesHealthIndicatorConfiguration did not match due to @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans

2016-07-22 10:07:23.577 TRACE 7628 --- [restartedMain] o.s.b.a.condition.OnBeanCondition        : Condition OnBeanCondition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration matched due to @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource,javax.sql.XADataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans
2016-07-22 10:07:23.578 DEBUG 7628 --- [restartedMain] a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader : Registered bean definition for imported class 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration'
2016-07-22 10:07:23.578 DEBUG 7628 --- [restartedMain] a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader : Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource()
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Spring Boot?  Is there a way to change the order so that the datasource is initialised first?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by running the app from Eclipse.  I also had a `TestApplication` class in src/test/java which had an exclusion for `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`.  I excluded the `TestApplication` class from the component scanning (via `excludeFilter` on `@ComponentScan`) and the health endpoint worked as expected (i.e. it included database information).